# Is it possible to make nginx stop listening on a port when no upstreams are online?

Tags: nginx

I have a domain with multiple IP addresses assigned so that if one of the servers is offline, clients check another one automatically. Nginx is configured similar to this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}

upstream backend {
    server localhost:1234;
}
```

However when the service at 1234 fails, nginx starts returning error 502 (which is expected), and the clients don't try the next IP. But if I stop nginx on the failed instance completely - e.g. start listening on 80, the clients connect to another working server.

Is there a way to configure nginx to refuse connections to server port if upstream is offline?

Comment: Why not configure your client to try another ip in case of 502?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, because it's what any client does, like FireFox or curl - and I can't configure users' browsers

Comment: There is 444 response code, that will terminate connection, but I guess it won't help. Nginx can't refuse connection, because it will not go to upstream unless there is connection that requires so.

Comment: Or you could have a watchdog that periodically check some url and stops nginx if it return 502

Comment: @AlexeyTen, yeah I'm going to go with that - did not find anything to help me in nginx conf

Answer (score 0):

why not use a fallback location?

add this to your location (alter)

```
try_files $uri @my_fallback;


location @my_fallback {
    proxy_pass http://example.com:12345; #other url here
}
```

Comment: I'd rather have client connect to the working server directly than have data proxied through broken server

Comment: Use instead of a proxy_pass a return directive here then. `return 302 http://example.com:12345;`